# Algorithm to find all ways to distribute N objects into M collections

Tags: javascript, algorithm, partitioning, combinatorics

Given a collection with M subcollections, what's a good algorithm (preferably an implementation in Javascript, but any other language or pseudocode would be great as well) to find all possible distributions of N objects into the M subcollections?

For example, given a setup like this:

```
var collection = [[],[],[]];
var items = ['a','b','c']
```

I would like the results to look like this

```
[['a','b','c'],[],[]]
[['a','b'],['c'],[]]
[['a','c'],['b'],[]]
[['a'],['b','c'],[]]
[['b','c'],['a'],[]]
[['b'],['c','a'],[]]
[['c'],['b','a'],[]]
[['a'],['b'],['c']]
[[],['a','b','c'],[]]
[[],['a'],['b','c']]
// etc
```

N can be larger than, smaller than, or equal to N. Also, in the example, I'm using characters as the items to be distributed, but I'd like the algorithm to be able to distribute objects of any type.

Comment: Algorithms are not "in" a language.  Implementations of an algorithm are in particular language.  In any case your question is too broad.  Don't ask everyone to solve your entire piece of work.  Do it yourself and only ask about specific parts that you get stuck on.

Comment: I think the algorithm I posted below should get you what you needed. It would be wonderful if @JK could confirm if I am correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every object should belong to some collection, so `M` variants exist for it.
For N objects there are `P=M^N` variants (N-th power of M).

So we can generate all numbers in range `0..P-1`, and consider them as M-base radix numbers.
If k-th digit of number in M-base representation is j, then k-th object belongs to j-th collection.

Example for your case `N=3, M=3, P=27`
number `12(dec)` is equal to `110(three-radix)`, so collection is

```
[[a], ['b','c'],[]]
```

pseudocode

```
for iii = 0 to Power(M, N) - 1
    Clear Collections
    i = iii //number of combination

    for k = 0 to N - 1 do

        j = i mod M     //integer modulo, % 
        //gives k-th digit of number i in M-radix representation
        //counting from right to left

        Collections[j].Add(Object[k])

        i = i div M     //integer division
    output Collections
```